# constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type; found : (T1, T2, T3, T4, T5)

Tags: scala, spark-graphx

I am new in spark-graphx and scala.
I write this method to verify if the score of the goal vertex has changed.

```
 def IsGoalVertexFound(graph: Graph[(VertexId,(Int,Float,Float,Float,String)),Float],goalVertex:(VertexId,(Int,Float,Float,Float))): Boolean ={
        var IsgoalFound:Boolean=false
        var targetVertex=graph.vertices.filter{ case (id,(_,gScore,_,_,_)) => id == goalVertex._1 && gScore!=Float.PositiveInfinity}
          if(targetVertex.isEmpty())
            IsgoalFound=true
        return IsgoalFound
      }
```

I get this error :

```
Error:(41, 54) constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;
 found   : (T1, T2, T3, T4, T5)
 required: (org.apache.spark.graphx.VertexId, (Int, Float, Float, Float, String))
    (which expands to)  (Long, (Int, Float, Float, Float, String))
    var targetVertex=graph.vertices.filter{ case (id,(_,gScore,_,_,_)) => id == goalVertex._1 && gScore!=Float.PositiveInfinity}
```

Any ideas? 
Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a serialization error.  Try pulling out the `goalVertex._1` parameter into a local variable, so that the `VertexId` is not serialized:

```
def IsGoalVertexFound(graph: Graph[(VertexId,(Int,Float,Float,Float,String)),Float],goalVertex:(VertexId,(Int,Float,Float,Float))): Boolean ={
    var IsgoalFound:Boolean=false
    val localGoal = goalVertex._1
    var targetVertex=graph.vertices.filter{ case (id,(_,gScore,_,_,_)) => id == localGoal && gScore!=Float.PositiveInfinity}
      if(targetVertex.isEmpty())
        IsgoalFound=true
    return IsgoalFound
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following solution and it works correctly:

```
 def IsGoalVertexFound(graph: Graph[(VertexId,(Int,Float,Float,Float,String)),Float],goalVertex:(VertexId,(Int,Float,Float,Float))): Boolean ={
    var IsgoalFound:Boolean=false
    var targetVertex=graph.vertices.filter{ case (id,attr) => id == goalVertex._1 && attr._2._2!=Float.PositiveInfinity}.first()
     // if(targetVertex.isEmpty())
      //  IsgoalFound=true
    return IsgoalFound
  }
```